# JMSException: Queue does not exist

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, messaging

I am new in JMS and want to create a basic MessageProducer who sends a message and MessageConsumer who receives the message asynchronously. When I run this code I get error message :

**MessageProducer.java**

```
package activemq.test;

import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.*;

public class MessageProducer{

    javax.jms.MessageProducer producer = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;

    public MessageProducer(){
        try {
                // Create a ConnectionFactory
                ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

                // Create a Connection
                connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.start();

                // Create a Session
                session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
                Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

                // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
                producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

                // Create a messages
                String text = "Hello world! From: MessageProducer";
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

                // Tell the producer to send the message
                System.out.println("Producer is going to send a message");
                producer.send(message);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(){
        try
          {
            // Create a messages
            String text = "Hello world! From: " + new Date();
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

            // Tell the producer to send the message
            System.out.println("Sent message: "+ message.hashCode());
            producer.send(message);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close(){

        // Clean up
        try {
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**MessageConsumer.java**

```
package activemq.test;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.*;

public class MessageConsumer implements ExceptionListener{

    Connection connection = null;
    javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    Session session = null;

    public MessageConsumer(){
        try {

            // Create a ConnectionFactory
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

            // Create a Connection
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            connection.setExceptionListener(this);

            // Create a Session
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

            // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

            MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() {
                public void onMessage(Message message) {
                    try {
                        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                            System.out.println("Received message"
                                    + textMessage.getText() + "'");
                        }
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        System.out.println("Caught:" + e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            consumer.setMessageListener(listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException exception) {
        System.out.println("JMS Exception occured.  Shutting down client.");        
    }

    public void close(){

        // Clean up
        try {
            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**AppMain.java**

```
public class AppMain {

    public static void main(final String arg[]) throws Exception
    {
        MessageProducer msProducer = new MessageProducer();

        msProducer.sendMessage();
        msProducer.close();

        MessageConsumer msConsumer = new MessageConsumer();

        msConsumer.close();
    }

}
```

When MessageConsumer is created, I get error message:

```
    Caught: javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ119017: Queue jms.queue.TEST.FOO does not exist
javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ119017: Queue jms.queue.TEST.FOO does not exist
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1405)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQSession.java:1925)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.<init>(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:275)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:1157)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:1101)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:1014)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:987)
    at activemq.test.MessageConsumer.<init>(MessageConsumer.java:36)
    at activemq.test.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:17)
Caused by: ActiveMQNonExistentQueueException[errorType=QUEUE_DOES_NOT_EXIST message=AMQ119017: Queue jms.queue.TEST.FOO does not exist]
    at org.apache.activemq.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.createConsumer(ServerSessionImpl.java:448)
    at org.apache.activemq.core.protocol.openwire.amq.AMQServerSession.createConsumer(AMQServerSession.java:326)
    at org.apache.activemq.core.protocol.openwire.amq.AMQConsumer.init(AMQConsumer.java:138)
    at org.apache.activemq.core.protocol.openwire.amq.AMQSession.createConsumer(AMQSession.java:144)
    at org.apache.activemq.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireProtocolManager.addConsumer(OpenWireProtocolManager.java:544)
    at org.apache.activemq.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection.processAddConsumer(OpenWireConnection.java:1118)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo.visit(ConsumerInfo.java:347)
    at org.apache.activemq.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection.bufferReceived(OpenWireConnection.java:272)
    at org.apache.activemq.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.activemq.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:332)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:507)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why I get this error when MessageConsumer is created, but don't get this error when MessageProducer is created.

I use ActiveMQServer as a broker:

**Server.java**

```
package activemq.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.activemq.api.core.TransportConfiguration;
import org.apache.activemq.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.activemq.core.config.impl.ConfigurationImpl;
import org.apache.activemq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.core.server.ActiveMQServer;
import org.apache.activemq.core.server.ActiveMQServers;

public class Server {
    public static void main(final String arg[]) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            // Step 1. Create the Configuration, and set the properties accordingly
            Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
            //we only need this for the server lock file
            configuration.setJournalDirectory("target/data/journal");
            configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(false); // http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-persistent-and-non-persistent-delivery.html
            configuration.setSecurityEnabled(false); // http://activemq.apache.org/security.html
            /**
             * this map with configuration values is not necessary (it configures the default values).
             * If you want to modify it to run the example in two different hosts, remember to also
             * modify the client's Connector at {@link EmbeddedRemoteExample}.
             */
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("host", "localhost");
            map.put("port", 61616);

            // https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/HornetQ_User_Guide/ch14s04.html
            TransportConfiguration transpConf = new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(),map);

            HashSet<TransportConfiguration> setTransp = new HashSet<TransportConfiguration>();
            setTransp.add(transpConf);

            configuration.setAcceptorConfigurations(setTransp); // https://github.com/apache/activemq-6/blob/master/activemq-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/spi/core/remoting/Acceptor.java

            // Step 2. Create and start the server
            ActiveMQServer server = ActiveMQServers.newActiveMQServer(configuration);
            server.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Believe the JVM: You didn't set up the queue.  Writing the code isn't sufficient.

Comment: @duffymo Sorry, but I don't understand. How Should I set the queue? Why don't I get this error when I create MessageProducer?

Comment: @Matt You don't get the error on MessageProducer because the message producer does not use the queue at that moment. The consumer does by setting a listener on it, so it tries to listen. Producer just has a producer waiting to be used. If you put the cl.createConsumer() in comment I'm pretty sure the sendMessage will give you that exception.

Comment: @Juru thanks for response, I get this exception when consumer is created (before the listener is set). Could you give me a hint how can i fix it?

Comment: Two doubtful things I have in mind: Something to do with the session and connection not being closed in between creating and using the queue. It doesn't make sense to have the producer and consumer use the same session anyway. Or that the queue is not really created until used (by putting a message on it). Could you do the sendMessage before the create consumer?

Comment: Please see my edited code. Yes, MessageProducer can send the message.

Comment: What are your settings on the broker? Do you have any authorization settings or a plain vanilla broker?

Comment: @Petter I use ActiveMQServer as a broker. Please see my edited post.

Comment: @Matt Just a little remark: You shouldn't call `connection.start()` until all consumers are created. So, move it all the way to the back.

Comment: @bvdb I did it according Alexcocia answer, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Matt have you tried/verified to see what happens if you remove the producer code ? Or switch the order of the producer and consumer code. I'm wondering if it is it always the 2nd one that fails.

Comment: @bvdb I tried it. Remove producer or create consumer at first, but still get the same exception at `consumer = session.createConsumer(destination)` line

Comment: @Matt just to be sure, "TEST.FOO" is not a topic is it ? Because that would require `createTopic` (i.e. not `createQueue`). (Just making sure, since the comments in your source code suggests that you would use it for topics as well)

Comment: @bvdb Yes, I am sure there is `createQueue`

Answer (score 1):

I think, in the producer, you are starting the connection before setting the destination.
Try it starting afterwards....

```
// Create a ConnectionFactory
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new
      ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

// Create a Connection
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

// Create a Session
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

// Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
connection.start();

// Create a messages
String text = "Hello world! From: MessageProducer";
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

// Tell the producer to send the message
System.out.println("Producer is going to send a message");
producer.send(message);
```

On the other hand, for the consumer, I suggest to implement MessageConsumer (instead of the Exception).
Once implemented, in the constructor you can initiate the consumer

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
connection = factory.createConnection();
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

// Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
consumer = session.createConsumer(destination).setMessageListener(this);
connection.start();
```

....
and then implement the onMessage method

```
 public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Received message"
                    + textMessage.getText() + "'");
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught:" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. I get the same exception.

Comment: Have you tried instatiate both producer and consumer, and then send the message?